# how to select parent rows which have less than two childs in same table

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

[Here is my table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLXFI.jpg) i have a table in phpmyadmin (i.e. members) and it contains details members details with parent child relation. and every member can have only 2 child members. 
This is what i have been doing this far.

```
function select_parent_can_have_child($limit = 0){
        $query = "";
        $query .= "SELECT parent_referal, COUNT(parent_referal) as parents";
        $query .= " FROM members GROUP BY parent_referal";
        $query .= " ORDER BY db_added ASC";

        $query = $this->db->query($query);
        if($query->num_rows()>0){
            $results = array();
            $count = 1;
            foreach($query->result() as $result){
                if($result->parents >= 2){
                    continue;
                };
                $results[] = $result;
                if($limit > 0 AND $limit == $count){
                    break;
                }
                $count++;
            }
            return $results;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide table structure?

Comment: i have included screenshot of my table structure @Mully

Comment: Better thana screenshot is a dbfiddle demo link ...if you wish to receive faster and higher quality support. `$query = "";` is pointless.  Show us your exact desired result from the provided sample data. Do you mean 2 direct children or two "descendants" (would a child and grandchild work?)?